# Space between custom taxonomy terms in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following to list the terms within my custom taxonomy

```
<?php $application_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'application');
  if(!empty($application_terms)){
    if(!is_wp_error( $application_terms )){

      foreach($application_terms as $application){
        echo $application->slug; 
      }
    }
  } 
?>
```

The code works fine and it displays the terms however, if a post type has two "application" terms assigned to it, the two terms appear without space in betweeen them e.g ig apple and banana it appears applebanana. How do you change the code so that there is space in between the terms?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of slugs and implode it with a blank space

```
$application_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'application');
if ( $application_terms && !is_wp_error( $application_terms ) {
    $slugs = wp_list_pluck( $application_terms, 'slug' );
    $string = implode( ' ', $slugs );
    echo $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It should work in the way, you want it to be**

```
<?php $application_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'application');
  if(!empty($application_terms)){
    if(!is_wp_error( $application_terms )){
      $i = 0;
      foreach($application_terms as $application){
         if($i>0) 
         echo ', ';
         echo $application->slug;
         $i++; 
      }
    }
  } 
?>
```

so if a post have two category assigned, it will display like **apple, banana**

Comment: no.. it will display properly ... only one statement is under if condition.